# Restrict the apps

Tags: wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

I am using EMM 1.1.0 from wso2 on my Android 4.4.2.  Both the server and client are running.  The phone will be COPE devices.  I am not finding the ways to achieve the following:

- I want to restrict the apps that can be run on the mobile device. I can use white list/black list but that works only for the apps that are listed, there is a chance that the device owner could install some custom app which I want to prevent, how can I achieve it?
- The phone can be unregistered and wso2 app itself can be uninstalled by the device owner. How can I prevent the user from not doing so?
- What is the best way to have the functionality of firewall, i.e., restrict the traffic from the phone to a single IP, using emm?

Answer (score 0):

To address your questions,

1) You could have alternatives. Suggestion would be to entirely block the the custom app installation or prevent it from being getting opened when it has specifically being blocked by the EMM side. For that you could enhance the functionality in EMM agent and block the blacklisted app openings.

2) If this is a system app this could be prevented. Also check [Device admin APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

You cancheck whether its possible in Knox as well.

3) Enhancing the codebase to restrict to that single IP will work. But recommended solution is to filter that from the proxy/firewall in your network system so it could have minimal load into your EMM server.